# Import SMS/MMS messages and Call log backup to Fresh LineageOS

Tags: backup, import

I switch from Google Android to LineageOS and prepare all my data to be ready for the switch. Everything is on Nextcloud so, Contact, Photos, etc are already out of my device. I want to backup SMS/MMS messages and Call log. I can backup them with Samsung Switch, but is there a way to import them in LineageOS after?

## Update 1

I'll not install LineageOS with Google Apps support, so any apps from Google Play will not be able to run after the LineageOS install. I can install app from F-Droid or run command line in Linux shell if needed.

Thank you!

Comment: [Very reliable app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore)

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but I don't want to use Google Play services. Question is updated.

Comment: I found "SMS Backup+" on F-Droid. I know Google introduce sensitivity scopes, and as a result some API don't work anymore like MMS backup. I'll give it a try...

Comment: But it stores backup on IMAP instead of local storage. Bad luck.

Comment: See the app description, it can backup to cloud (few types of cloud) or to xml format

Comment: which app can access device without google play services? you probably have some misconceive of android

Comment: @alecxs Probably. I talk about the install part of LineageOS ("Optionally, download additional application packages such as Google Apps [...]")[https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/hlte/install#installing-lineageos-from-recovery] that I'll not install. So, without Google Play, no "SMS Backup & Restore", am I wrong ?

Comment: *Optionally* is a funny wording. android apps rely on google APIs, you need at least a replacement for GmsCore (like [microG](https://github.com/microg/android_packages_apps_GmsCore/wiki), [Open GApps](https://opengapps.org) or [MindTheGapps](https://gitlab.com/MindTheGapps/vendor_gapps/-/blob/qoppa/README.md)). btw you can download apps from [Uptodown](https://en.uptodown.com/android), [APK Pure](https://apkpure.com), [APKMirror](https://www.apkmirror.com) or similar without using google play store

Comment: Thanks for additional informations.

Comment: of course it's always possible with direct access from cmd line but [SQLite](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/5736) is a hassle for [Write-Ahead Log](https://sqliteforensictoolkit.com/how-not-to-examine-sqlite-wal-files) enabled databases. to keep it simple i personally prefer [Migrate](https://www.xda-developers.com/migrate-app-switch-custom-roms) or [MyPhoneExplorer](https://www.fjsoft.at/en) but the above apps are good choice too

Comment: I know my Android SMS/MMS database are stored in SQLite. A simple import/export from CLI should work. But I don't know how LineageOS manage SMS/MMS and Call logs database. That's why I ask for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @beeshyams for his comment.

## TL;DR

Just install [SMS Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore) or download it from [apkmirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/synctech-pty-ltd/sms-backup-restore/sms-backup-restore-10-07-106-release/sms-backup-restore-10-07-106-android-apk-download/). Copy apk to SD card. Do a backup of SMS/MMS messages (don't forget to enable MMS images/file/etc in advanced settings) and Call log to SD card.  After the switch to LineageOS, install APK from SD card and import SMS/MMS messages and Call log. Done.

## Story (and issues)

I finally switch from Android 5 on my Samsung Galaxy Note 3 (don't laugh, it still rocks!) to LineageOS 16.0 following [Install LineageOS on hlte](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/hlte/install).

After a backup of my data (see *TL;DR*), I boot in recovery mode and at the [Installing a custom recovery using heimdall](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/hlte/install#installing-a-custom-recovery-using-heimdall) step, the command

```
heimdall flash --RECOVERY <recovery_filename>.img --no-reboot
```

did not work properly.

My shell fail with :

```
ERROR: Failed to confirm end of file transfer sequence!
ERROR: RECOVERY upload failed!
```

and my device show a "`SECURE CHECK FAIL : recovery`".

From [this post](http://teamuscellular.com/Forum/topic/8195-solved-secure-download-fail-recovery/),

> "it was the **Samsung Reactivation Lock** that was blocking me. Upon booting the phone, going into Apps > Setttings > Security and then typing in my samsung account password I was able to disable the lock [...]"

And recovery file upload success!

After the LineageOS install, I use SMS Backup & Restore again to import data.