# Is it a viable option to modify ROM image directly instead of compiling?

Tags: custom-roms, rom, customization, bloatware

I have an archive of my stock ROM with partition images inside and I have combined sparsechunks into a single images (this specific because it seems that there are various formats with ambiguous naming).
Now I am able to mount combined images of ext2 partitions and make modifications to the files/directories.

Main goal is to remove google and various other bloat, I know how to manually remove applications from android.
But I read that this is not correct way and that this might make device unstable or create various problems and that I should modify and compile AOSP/lineageos insted. (source of information is XDA though...)

Only compilation of AOSP/lineageos requires too much knowledge thought, not to mention attempting to make modifications to the project which takes hundreds of gigabytes of storage.

Will 'debloating'/'degoogeleing' ROM image make my device unstable or possibly raise other problems and something I should not do?
Or does it depend and I should maybe try and see for myself?

I know of custom android distributions like lineageos - I have this official POS (piece of software) installed currently and it has too many bugs for my taste, phone being just a tool and not a way of life for me, I don't find it appealing to wait and hope for possible resolution.

Comment: Custom ROMs usually don't break after removing Google apps. But OEM provided ROMs are likely to break because they make Google-specific changes to the Android framework and remove core AOSP components in favor of Google products. OEMs are bound to sign contracts with Google for releasing devices with Google Play Services and accompanying apps which are privileged apps and tightly integrated with Android framework. If removing an app after installing ROM makes it unstable, then modifying ROM image won't make a difference either. You need to modify source code, not filesystem components.

Comment: OEM ROM of motorola G I was planning to modify. I got a better and bigger picture of situation. I will flash OEM ROM and make modifications on live system little by little, until something breaks. If nothing breaks, then good. Much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: that [comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/228441/import-sms-mms-messages-and-call-log-backup-to-fresh-lineageos?noredirect=1#comment298565_228441) might be interesting for you